# Idiomatic, classy, open-source examples of Cocoa Interfaces?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Greetings, I'm currently learning Cocoa and Objective-C. I've run through "all" the tutorials and I'm fairly comfortable with the ObjC language. What I'm looking for now is to learn Cocoa idioms and see real code used in nice-looking Cocoa apps.

It seems like serious apps (iTunes, etc.) don't just drop in the IB elements. They do a lot more with code to tweak them to look good. (Example: the iTunes playlist drawer. How does one go about getting that styling?)

Here are some examples of nice UI's that are open source that I've found:

- Smultron ([current home](http://www.peterborgapps.com/smultron), [open-source fork](https://github.com/jfmoy/Fraise))
- [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/)
- [Vienna](http://www.vienna-rss.org/)
- [Gitnub](https://github.com/Caged/gitnub/wiki)

Any other suggestions on Open-Source apps that have great Cocoa user interfaces?

Comment: I may be incorrect but I believe iTunes is built with Carbon not Cocoa.  Additionally I heard the plan was to bring it to Cocoa to support multi touch gestures. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: iTunes playlist drawer? What is this myserious element? Do you mean the source list? Look up NSDrawer and I think you'll agree there isn't a drawer iTunes!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might want to look at [BWToolkit](http://www.brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/), by Brandon Walkin.  It's pretty awesome, containing an elegant collection of UI elements and other objects.  The source code is provided so you can see how custom controls and views were created.

Brandon even provides some walkthrough movies, such as "Creating an iCal interface in 3 minutes."

A few other open source apps to dig into are [Camino](http://caminobrowser.org), [Colloquy](http://colloquy.info/) for both Mac and iPhone, [Adium](http://adium.im/), and [Quicksilver](http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-alchemy/) (lots of UI customization).

Comment: Adium has a very nice interface, but the implementation is… hairy. Its biggest problem is poor separation between model and controller, manifesting mainly as too many controllers. I wouldn't recommend emulating that implementation.