# Good open source Mac OSX App for code study?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm rewriting my Mac OSX App (which is full of spaghetti code), but before I do so, I'd like to take some time and study an existing Mac OSX App.

Is there something good available on github.com or elsewhere where I can learn good coding conventions?

Specifically I'm looking for Mac app that makes use for CoreData, NSOutlineView, Bindings, etc.

Thanks

Comment: How about the Apple examples you can find in the documentation? There are lots of programming guides for all kinds of topics. Just a thought.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open source Objective-C projects with high quality code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067529/open-source-objective-c-projects-with-high-quality-code)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some places to start with:

- [Sample Code from the Apple Developer Website](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/index.html#topic=Sample+Code&section=Resource+Types)
- Looking up the source code from an open-source program. Here's a [list of open source programs from opensourcemac.org](http://opensourcemac.org/) and another from [Mac.AppStorm](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/utilities-roundups/30-great-open-source-mac-apps/). [Adium](http://trac.adium.im/), [Cyberduck](http://trac.cyberduck.ch/), [Vienna](http://www.vienna-rss.org/?page_id=16), [Transmission](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/) are some solid apps I've used (though, not sure they make use of all of the features you've mentioned).

Comment: Didn't know those apps were open source.  Thanks!